# insert html tag in join method at angular 2+ not working

Tags: json, angular, join

Is there any reason this is not working?

The `<br>` or any html tags is not interpreted.

in HTML:

```
{{data.prContent.join(' <br> ')}}
```

in Json file:

```
 "prContent": [
              "Banana", 
              "Orange", 
              "Apple", 
              "Mango"
            ],
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent element contains only that interpolation, you can set the content with `[innerHTML]`:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data.prContent.join('<br/>')"></div>
```

Otherwise, you can combine the array items with multiple interpolations, using an `*ngFor` loop:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data.prContent; let isLast = last">
  {{item}} <br *ngIf="!isLast" />
</ng-container>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ii9yc2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.